# How to create multi-columns "reference" index (join index) in c# model with EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I know how to create common multi-columns index in c# which is mapping table in database.
But I encounter one specifical question on Multiple columns index, here is the code:

```
public class Table1
{
  [Index("MultipleIndexColumn",1)]
  public Table2 Table2_ID {get; set;}
  [Index("MultipleIndexColumn",2)]
  public Table3 Table3_ID {get; set;}
  [Index("MultipleIndexColumn",3)]
  public DateTime CreateDateTime {get; set;}
}
```

EF6 will generate t-sql like this :

`create index MultipleIndexColumn on Table1(CreateDateTime)` which is not the expected sql sentence.

here is my expected :
`create index MultipleIndexColumn on Table1(Table2_ID,Table3_ID,CreateDateTime)`

Could you guys help about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `index keys` **only on** `Primitive Datatypes`.So try as shown below.

```
public class Table1
{

      [ForeignKey("Table2_ID")]
      public virtual Table2  Table2 { get; set; }

      [Index("MultipleIndexColumn",1)]
      public int Table2_ID { get; set; }

      [ForeignKey("Table3_ID")]
      public virtual Table3  Table3 { get; set; }

      [Index("MultipleIndexColumn",2)]
      public int Table3_ID { get; set; }

      [Index("MultipleIndexColumn",3)]
      public DateTime CreateDateTime {get; set;}

    }
```

Comment: Thank you Inspire me, I get the solution

Comment: Thank you for Inspiring me.

Comment: No problem ! :D

Answer (score 1):

Thank https://stackoverflow.com/users/1077309/sampath for inspiring me.
Here is the Solution:
as https://stackoverflow.com/users/1077309/sampath  said You can create index keys only on Primitive Datatypes

```
public class Table1
{

      [ForeignKey("Table2_ID")]
      public virtual Table2  Table2 { get; set; }
      // here is important
      [Index("MultipleIndexColumn",1)]
      public int Table2_ID { get; set; }

      [ForeignKey("Table3_ID")]
      public virtual Table3  Table3 { get; set; }
       // here is important
      [Index("MultipleIndexColumn",2)]
      public int Table3_ID { get; set; }

      [Index("MultipleIndexColumn",3)]
      public DateTime CreateDateTime {get; set;}

    }
```

as the code The EF6 generate the index as I expected,
create index MultipleIndexColumn on Table1(Table2_ID,Table3_ID,CreateDateTime)

and The EF6 Didn't generate redundant column Table3No,Table2No in database.
That's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your trouble might be in using "the navigation properties" = the reference types. You should try to define the foreign IDs as separate properties and mark them like:

```
public class Table1
{

  public Table2 Table2Ref {get; set;}

  public Table3 Table3Ref {get; set;}

  [Index("MultipleIndexColumn",3)]
  public DateTime CreateDateTime {get; set;}

  [Index("MultipleIndexColumn",1)]
  public int Table2Id {get; set;}
  [Index("MultipleIndexColumn",2)]
  public int Table3Id {get; set;}
}
```

**or you could use the fluent api instead**

You could use the Fluent API to define an index like that

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#PropertyIndex

> For a complete list of the settings available in IndexAttribute, see
>   the Index section of Code First Data Annotations. This includes
>   customizing the index name, creating unique indexes, and creating
>   multi-column indexes.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583#Index

Comment: If I did this , there will be no foreign key references constraint. and I know your approach can work, because the type is primitives type. I need the foreign key constraint